# "Installer enountered an error" for latest JDK 8 update on Mavericks

Tags: macos, java

I went to the oracle jdk installation website

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

and upon launching

> jdk-8u**51**-macosx-x64.dmg

the following error dialog immediately appears:

[image]

I have tried this several times with the same result.  Where do I look for specific error logs/messages ?

**Update** The older version 8u**40** does still work when I re-installed it.